# snack detach function does not work in IE

Tags: snackjs

I am using `snackjs` library.

`wrap.detach(namespace)` is throwing  `'Object Expected'` error in IE8.

Explanation:

```
detach: function (namespace){
      listenerMethod(this, 'detach', namespace, null, true)
      this.data(namespace, null)
      return this
},
function listenerMethod(wrapper, method, namespace, args){
    var data = wrapper.data(namespace)
    if (data)
    snack.each(data, function (listener){
      listener[method].apply(wrapper, args)
    })
    return wrapper
}
```

4th argument passed in `listenerMethod(this, 'detach', namespace, null, true)`  is `null`

so `listener[method].apply(wrapper, args)`
is giving error.

it is because in IE8

`function.apply(obj , null)` will throw error.